# How to set TLS to a service in EKS with PCA on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I created a TLS-enabled service with AWS PCA and cert-manager by this post:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-enabled-kubernetes-clusters-with-acm-private-ca-and-amazon-eks-2/
[image]

After I deployed a demo application with ingress, I tested access on control node

```
$ curl https://demo.my-org.com --cacert cacert.pem
```

Got message

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

The `cacert.pem` was downloaded from AWS PCA's Certificate body. Things look good in K8s for AWSPCAClusterIssuer and Certificate. The certificate description got these events:

```
$ kubectl describe certificate rsa-cert-2048 -n acm-pca-lab-demo
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From          Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----          -------
  Normal  Issuing    47m   cert-manager  Existing issued Secret is not up to date for spec: [spec.commonName spec.dnsNames]
  Normal  Reused     47m   cert-manager  Reusing private key stored in existing Secret resource "rsa-example-cert-2048"
  Normal  Requested  47m   cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "rsa-cert-2048-pp4c4"
  Normal  Issuing    47m   cert-manager  The certificate has been successfully issued
```

If I access from browser got 502 error. The certificate page shown a fake certificate and an alt DNS name.

[image]
[image]

I'm sure the private CA in AWS was actived successfully. Its arn and region were been set to the EKS node policy and AWSPCAClusterIssuer. What's wrong about the settings? How to diagnose the issue?

---

## deployed resources

I checked the deployed resources in acm-pca-lab-demo namespace.

```
$ kubectl get secret -n acm-pca-lab-demo
NAME                    TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-jmxt7     kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      10h
rsa-example-cert-2048   kubernetes.io/tls                     3      10h

$ kubectl get all -n acm-pca-lab-demo
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-world-57df4c69f9-nnjrl   1/1     Running   0          10h
pod/hello-world-57df4c69f9-r8f4p   1/1     Running   0          10h
pod/hello-world-57df4c69f9-xgm6w   1/1     Running   0          10h

NAME                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/hello-world   ClusterIP   102.30.45.163   <none>        80/TCP    10h

NAME                          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/hello-world   3/3     3            3           10h

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/hello-world-57df4c69f9   3         3         3       10h

$ kubectl get ingress -n acm-pca-lab-demo
NAME                   CLASS    HOSTS             ADDRESS                                                                          PORTS     AGE
acm-pca-demo-ingress   <none>   demo.my-org.com   11111111111111111111111111111111-2222222222222222.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com    80, 443   10h
```

On the browser, I also got these messages:

```
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.


HTTP Strict Transport Security: false

HTTP Public Key Pinning: false
```

---

## certificate file

I downloaded the PCA .pem file from AWS console here. Is it correct?

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` started file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your **ingress** configuration, share the YAML config-if possible which you have used with application deployment.

there could be chances there is not **secret** attached to ingress, due to that **K8s Nginx ingress** **controller** by default attaching the default **FAKE** cert instead of your generated cert.

For example :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: acm-pca-demo-ingress
  namespace: acm-pca-lab-demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.rsa-2048.example.com
    secretName: rsa-example-cert-2048
  rules:
  - host: www.rsa-2048.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-world
            port:
              number: 80
```

as shown above `rsa-example-cert-2048`, make sure your secret exists in the namespace in which ingress there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the deployment for this demo. It seems the secret is in the same namespace. I added some information to the bottom of the question. Maybe the cert itself has some problem. I just downloaded it from AWS console. But this time there isn't the 502 bad gateway. I can see the site. Only TLS doesn't work.

Comment: yes, there could be a chance of missing out on something into the cert or secret.

Comment: I added `certificate file` get way to the bottom of the question. Is that correct?

Comment: there is chances if cert is self singed browser wont allow it unless you add it as trusted in browser.

Comment: Oh, maybe that's the issue. So the guide [TLS-enabled Kubernetes clusters with ACM Private CA and Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tls-enabled-kubernetes-clusters-with-acm-private-ca-and-amazon-eks-2/) isn't a common way if use PCA as a TLS solution? It seems even Let's Encrypt is better for browser.

Comment: Yes, let's encrypt is better but i have not read whole solution properly if you are using ACM in the background also it uses let encrypt but custom CA and self singed won't get trusted by the browser unless we add them.

Comment: The solution in the link doesn't use lets encrypt. It is using PCA and cert-manager.